# Why am I getting a StopIteration error when using next()?

Tags: python, error-handling, iterator, stopiteration

I am not able to clarify my self over the use of `next()` in python(3).

I have a data :

```
chr pos ms01e_PI    ms01e_PG_al ms02g_PI    ms02g_PG_al ms03g_PI    ms03g_PG_al ms04h_PI    ms04h_PG_al
2   15881989    4   C|C 6   A|C 7   C|C 7   C|C
2   15882091    4   A|T 6   A|T 7   T|A 7   A|A
2   15882148    4   T|T 6   T|T 7   T|T 7   T|G
```

and I read it like:

**Works fine**

```
c = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(data), dialect=csv.excel_tab)
print(c)
print(list(c))
```

**Works fine**

```
c = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(data), dialect=csv.excel_tab)
print(c)
keys = next(c)
print('keys:', keys)
```

**But, now there is a problem.**

```
c = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(data), dialect=csv.excel_tab)
print(c)
print(list(c))
keys = next(c)
print('keys:', keys)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2   15882601    4   C|C 9   C|C 6   C|C 5   T|C

  File "/home/everestial007/Test03.py", line 24, in <module>
keys = next(c)
  File "/home/everestial007/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/csv.py", line 110, in __next__

    row = next(self.reader)

StopIteration
```

**Why does `print(keys)` after `print(list(c))` gives `StopIteration`?** I read the documentation but I am not clear on this particular example.

Comment: When you call `list(c)` you consume the iterator.  The iterator is empty now, and there is no next item. You might want to read up on generators in general.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The error isn't with the `print` statement. It's with the `keys = next(c)` line. Consider a simpler example which reproduces your issue.

```
a = (i ** 2 for i in range(5))  

a           # `a` is a generator object
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x150e286c0>
```

```
list(a)     # calling `list` on `a` will exhaust the generator
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]

next(a)     # calling `next` on an exhausted generator object raises `StopIteration`
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2076-3f6e2eea332d> in <module>()
----> 1 next(a)

StopIteration:
```

What happens is that `c` is an iterator object (very similar to the *generator* `a` above), and is meant to be iterated over once until it is exhausted. Calling `list` on this object will exhaust it, so that the elements can be collected into a list.

Once the object has been exhausted, it will not produce any more elements. At this point, the generator mechanism is designed to raise a `StopIteration` if you attempt to iterate over it even after it has been exhausted. Constructs such as `for` loops listen for this error, silently swallowing it, however, `next` returns the raw exception as soon as it has been raised.

Comment: This kind of error can also be raised when the generator is empty since the beginning of the execution. Ex. using ```os.walk``` as a generator that returns paths from a directory, if the directory doesn't exist, ```os.walk``` will be empty so ```next()``` will raise the ```StopIteration``` error.