# I am having IndentationError Problem & unable to do proper Indentation

Tags: python, python-3.x, indentation

I am having a problem with Indentation in my python script

This is my Code

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests
from itertools import cycle
import traceback
def get_proxies():
    url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    parser = fromstring(response.text)
    proxies = set()
    for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:10]:
        if i.xpath('.//td[7][contains(text(),"yes")]'):
           proxy = ":".join([i.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')[0], i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0]])
           proxies.add(proxy)
    return proxies

    proxies = get_proxies()
    proxy_pool = cycle(proxies)
    url = 'https://httpbin.org/ip'
    for i in range(1,11):
#Get a proxy from the pool
      proxy = next(proxy_pool)  
      print("Request #%d"%i)
      try:
                response = requests.get(url,proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy})
                print(response.json())
      except:

                print("Skipping. Connnection error")
```

There isn't any problem with the code.
I am just having trouble doing the proper Indentation.

Comment: Un indent lines after the end of your function

Comment: A problem with indentation *is* a problem with the code; it's just not necessarily a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete the space before `proxies`, and the same for the rest of your code:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests
from itertools import cycle
import traceback
def get_proxies():
   url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/'
   response = requests.get(url)
   parser = fromstring(response.text)
   proxies = set()
   for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:10]:
       if i.xpath('.//td[7][contains(text(),"yes")]'):
          proxy = ":".join([i.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')[0], 
          i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0]])
          proxies.add(proxy)
   return proxies

proxies = get_proxies()
proxy_pool = cycle(proxies)
url = 'https://httpbin.org/ip'
for i in range(1,11):
#Get a proxy from the pool
   proxy = next(proxy_pool)  
   print("Request #%d"%i)
   try:
            response = requests.get(url,proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy})
            print(response.json())
   except:

            print("Skipping. Connnection error")
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 22, in <module>
    proxy = next(proxy_pool)  
StopIteration`

Comment: This error is due to the `next()` method you used

Comment: What should I do with the `next()` method??

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180209/stop-iteration-error-when-using-next) or just google it.